# using loop for sorting values php

Tags: php, mysql

i have the next code:

```
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col0_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[0]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col1_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[1]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col2_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[2]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col3_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[3]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col4_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[4]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col5_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[5]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col6_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[6]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col7_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[7]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col8_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[8]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col9_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[9]; ?></a></td>
<td><a href="index.php?order_var=<?php echo $col10_var; ?>"><?php echo $col[10]; ?></a></td>
```

and in other php file

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//include 'countfields.php';
if ( isset ( $_GET['order_var'] ) )
{
        $order_var = $_GET['order_var'];
       for($i = 0 ; $i < 11; $i++) { 
        switch ( $order_var )
        {
        case 'col'.$i.'_asc':
                        $order_var = $col[$i]." ASC";
                        break;
                case 'col'.$i.'_dsc':
                        $order_var = $col[$i]." DESC";
                        break;

        }
        }
}
else
{
        $order_var = $col[0]." ASC";
}

$col0_var = "col0_asc";
$col1_var = "col1_asc";
$col2_var = "col2_asc";
$col3_var = "col3_asc";
$col4_var = "col4_asc";
$col5_var = "col5_asc";
$col6_var = "col6_asc";
$col7_var = "col7_asc";
$col8_var = "col8_asc";
$col9_var = "col9_asc";
$col10_var = "col10_asc";

if ( $order_var == $col[0]." ASC" )
{
        $col0_var = "col0_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[0]." DESC" )
{
        $col0_var = "col0_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[1]." ASC" )
{
        $col1_var = "col1_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[1]." DESC" )
{
        $col1_var = "col1_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[2]." ASC" )
{
        $col2_var = "col2_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[2]." DESC" )
{
        $col2_var = "col2_asc";
}

 if ( $order_var == $col[3]." ASC" )
{
        $col3_var = "col3_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[3]." DESC" )
{
        $col3_var = "col3_asc";
}
if ( $order_var == $col[4]." ASC" )
{
        $col4_var = "col4_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[4]." DESC" )
{
        $col4_var = "col4_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[5]." ASC" )
{
        $col5_var = "col5_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[5]." DESC" )
{
        $col5_var = "col5_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[6]." ASC" )
{
        $col6_var = "col6_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[6]." DESC" )
{
        $col6_var = "col6_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[7]." ASC" )
{
        $col7_var = "col7_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[7]." DESC" )
{
        $col7_var = "col7_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[8]." ASC" )
{
        $col8_var = "col8_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[8]." DESC" )
{
        $col8_var = "col8_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[9]." ASC" )
{
        $col9_var = "col9_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[9]." DESC" )
{
        $col9_var = "col9_asc";
}

if ( $order_var == $col[10]." ASC" )
{
        $col10_var = "col10_dsc";
}
else if ( $order_var == $col[10]." DESC" )
{
        $col10_var = "col10_asc";
}

?>
```

The `$col` array contains :

```
array('IDClient',
      'DenClient',
      'DataContract',
      'TipAbonament',
      'CUI',
      'AdresaClient',‌​
      'PersContact',
      'TelefonClient',
      'EmailClient',
      'BancaClient',
      'ContBancarClient');
```

The query is:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM $table1 ORDER BY $order_var";
```

I want to sort the values from a mysql table using a loop, because i have various tables, so i won't be needed to change the php code. I tried various ways but none of them is working. Maybe you are smartest... thank you

Comment: Why don't you sort them in the query?

Comment: Show us the SQL code that `$order_var` is being used in please

Comment: Use "Order by" to sort the data in SQL.

Comment: @Code-Monk I think she is, this code is just generating the ORDER BY clause in a wierd and hopefully wonderful way

Comment: $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM $table1 ORDER BY $order_var";

Comment: And what is in `$col[0] to $col[11]`... edit your question, dont use comment for new information

Answer (score 3):

This process would seem a whole lot simpler if you changed your processing so that your HTML anchors had 2 parameters like this

```
<td>
  <a href="index.php?var=<?php echo $col[0];?>&order=desc"><?php echo $col[0];?></a>
  <a href="index.php?var=<?php echo $col[1];?>&order=desc"><?php echo $col[1];?></a>

  ...
</td>
```

Then building your query would be very simple

```
<?php
   include 'connect.php';
   //include 'countfields.php';
   if ( !isset($_GET['var']) || !isset($_GET['order']) )
   {
       // throw errors
   }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table1 
           ORDER BY {$_GET['var']} {$_GET['order']}";
```

I have of course missed out the $_GET sanitisation and validation checks, thats down to you.

Not quite sure how you decide on whether the sort should be Ascending or Descending but I hope this helps you simplify your processing. A simple process is so much easier to build, maintain and debug.